"Fitting for the start" x "Fitting for the beginning"
In the song "Can't Stand Me Now" by The Libertines it is said:
An ending fitting for the start
You twist and tore our love apart
Your light fingers threw the dark
Shattered the lamp and into darkness it cast us
When I translate this text into Portuguese and then back into English using online translators (an exercise I always do, usually out of curiosity or simply for fun) instead of "for the start" it always gives me "for the beginning". Are both options correct and have the same meaning in this case? Or would the best option be to actually use "for the beginning" and the use of "for the start" was chosen somewhat forcibly to get the rhyme with the expression "dark"?

First of all, automatic translation is a really bad for songs, literature and poetry. Please look up start and beginning in a dictionary before posting.

I did this, and I searched in more than one dictionary, and the research I did led me to believe that the best option would be to use "beginning", although I was not sure that the use of "start" should be avoided. As "start" is used in the song in question, I decided to try to resolve this question here and, as always, I got good information. Thanks.

The two words start and beginning mean the same.  This is just about all we have on learning English.
The song writer used start to rhyme with apart.  This makes sense.
Your online translator probably looked just at ending and fitting and hence chose beginning. However, beginning doesn’t rhyme with apart.  Another solution is for it to rhyme with the last word of the third line, but the latter happens to be dark.  So the flow wouldn't go well.

In lyrics, a word like parched would rhyme with "apart" better than "beginning," would, even though it makes not much sense. The writer could even have gone with beginning/spinning.

@Itamar In fact, "beginning" is the more common choice as a noun.
